# How to upgrade tensorflow with GPU on google colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Currently google colaboratory uses tensorflow 1.4.1. I want to upgrade it to 1.5.0 version. Each time when i executed `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow` command, notebook instance succesfully upgrades the tensorflow version to 1.5.0. But after upgrade operation tensorflow instance only supports "CPU".

When i have executed this command it shows nothing :

`from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()`

Should there be another way for upgrading tensorflow ? such as upgrading to tensorflow-gpu package ? Also when will notebooks will come with upgraded tensorflows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you will install gpu version `!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0` it will still fail to import it because of the cuda libraries. Currently I have not found a way to use 1.5 version with GPU. So I would rather use 1.4.1 with gpu than 1.5 without gpu.

You can send them a feedback ( <kbd>Home</kbd>  -  <kbd>Send Feedback</kbd> ) and hopefully if enough people will send something similar, they will update the new gpu version.

Comment: I suspect about that. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

As of 2020, Colab can run Tensorflow 2.0. Uninstall the current version of Tensorflow:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and simply reinstall using pip.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

If you so choose, you can also install the beta version with

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

Once you've reinstalled Tensorflow, make sure you don't forget to restart the runtime under the Runtime tab.

A native solution is to start your code with

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

Comment: I did it, but after I restart the runtime and import tensorflow, it is not the version 2.0.0 I  tried to reinstall

Comment: From my understanding, Colab has one version of tensorflow which it updates time to time, under the umbrella term 2.x. If there was a specific version you wanted, I'm not sure if there is a solution, although I would appreciate input from other users

Answer (score 4):

Google Colaboratory seems to now support tensorflow up to version `1.6.0rc1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

#'1.6.0-rc1'
```

And the gpu should work if you [enable the GPU hardware accelerator](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d). Then, you can test if things are working:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Output:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 14621691266205111434, name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 198836224
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
 }
 incarnation: 17821632640358169265
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7"]
```

Comment: Yes, i also confirm that, thanks. Giving feed back just get the job done :)

Comment: Don't require to execute "!pip install -U tensorflow-gpu". If GPU acceleration is enabled it just works.

Comment: I see, edited to remove pip install tensorflow-gpu :)

Comment: downgrading to `v1.4.1` because I can't seem to load pre-trained weights with `v1.6.0`. anyone else having this problem? see:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17269

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this will not work. Look at Salvador's answer.

Uninstall tensorflow

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y
```

install `tensorflow-gpu`

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0
```

Comment: i'll try and give you the feedback. But what about CUDA 9 and cudnn 7 ?? tensorflow 1.5.0 requires these packages